Color Accessibility Challenges in Einstein for Developers VS Code Extension
I prefer using a light theme in VS Code, because I have red-green colorblindness (Deuteranopia).
I’ve found some themes specifically designed for Deuteranopia that work well for me, but the dark theme rendered in the Einstein for Developers extension causes significant eye strain.
I’m not sure if this is specific to the Einstein extension or a general VS Code setting for extensions.
Although most people probably don’t have an issue with it, it’s challenging for me.
Has anyone with similar visual challenges found a way to make the colors more accessible or have any suggestions for adjustments? (Of course, I'm aware I can copy and paste as a workaround!)

